# Accessing a field in an array of CKRecordZone?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, cloudkit

Here is what the array looks like:

```
Optional([<CKRecordZone: 0x155f0dc0; zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__, capabilities=(none)>, <CKRecordZone: 0x155e8370; zoneID=MedicalRecord:__defaultOwner__, capabilities=(Atomic,Sync,Share)>])
```

As you can see I have two elements in this array, one with the *zoneID=_defaultZone* and another one with the *zoneID=MedicalRecord*. How can I get only the element with the `zoneID` = MedicalRecord? I tried the following but it isn't working:

```
if let index = recordZone?.index(of: CKRecordZone(zoneName: "MedicalRecord")) {
     print("Index is: \(index)")
     self.sendHeartRate(id: (recordZone?[index].zoneID)!)
}
```

It's never running this `if let` block 'cause `index`is always nil...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation

The index in your `if let` block is always nil because in this line:

```
if let index = recordZone?.index(of: CKRecordZone(zoneName: "MedicalRecord")) {
```

the `CKRecordZone(zoneName...` is a completely new object, separate from the one that already exists in the array. It may have the same zone name as the one you are trying to retrieve ("MedicalRecord"), but nevertheless they are still two distinct objects. (See below.)

### Reference

Demonstration code I created:

```
let zone = CKRecordZone(zoneName: "MedicalZone")
    let defaultZone = CKRecordZone.default()
    let zoneArray = [defaultZone, zone]
    let idx = zoneArray.index(of: zone)
    print("*** Zone index: \(idx)")
    let z = zoneArray[idx!]
    print("*** z: \(z)")

    if let i = zoneArray.index(of: zone) {
        print("*** Index is: \(i)")
        print("*** id: \(zoneArray[i].zoneID)!)")
    }

    let tempZ = CKRecordZone(zoneName: "MedicalZone")

    if let index = zoneArray.index(of: tempZ)) {
        print("*** Index is: \(index)")
        print("*** id: \(zoneArray[index].zoneID)!)")
    }
```

As you can see, the first `MedicalZone`, the one in the array, is different from the latter `MedicalZone`, that was created afterwards:

```
(lldb) po zone
<CKRecordZone: 0x6180000b06e0; zoneID=MedicalZone:__defaultOwner__, capabilities=(Atomic,Sync)>


(lldb) po tempZ
<CKRecordZone: 0x6180000b0800; zoneID=MedicalZone:__defaultOwner__, capabilities=(Atomic,Sync)>
```

Comment: Thanks for everything, Anthony!!

Answer (score 0):

I could do it by doing the following!

```
let count = recordZones?.count
for item in recordZones!{
    let zoneName = (item.value(forKey: "_zoneID") as! CKRecordZoneID).value(forKey: "_zoneName") as! String
    print("zone name is: \(zoneName)")
    if(zoneName == "MedicalRecord"){
         self.sendHeartRate(id: item.zoneID, heartRate: heartRate)
    }
}
```